# PyQt: checkbox delegate inside tableview

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, qtableview, qitemdelegate

I have been able to make my checkbox editable in my tableview. 
They appear in my tableview but I can't do anything with them. 
It's like the flags are not properly set up.

```py
class CheckBox(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QGraphicsWidget.__init__(self)

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled

    def paint (self, painter, option, index):

        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)

        # picks up data from database
        checked = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole).toBool()

        # Then draw the checkbox
        box = QtGui.QStyleOptionButton()

        box.palette = option.palette
        box.rect = option.rect
        box.state = QtGui.QStyle.State_Enabled

        if checked:
            box.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_On
        else:
            box.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_Off

        style = QtGui.QApplication.instance().style()
        style.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_CheckBox, box, painter)
        painter.restore()
```

Hi this is a reviewed code based on Avaris comments to use checkrole instead of delegates. But I still can fix the problem. I cannot tick on the checkboxes, instead it shows me a spinbox.  it is reading the value (0 or 1) from the database correctly but I would like to hide this value. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

```py
class EditableShoSqlModel(QtSql.QSqlQueryModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(EditableShoSqlModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super(EditableShoSqlModel, self).flags(index)
        if index.column() in (12):
            flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        return flags

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        value2 = super(EditableShoSqlModel, self).data(index)
        if index.column() == 12 and role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole:
            if value2 != 0:
                return QtCore.Qt.Checked
            else:
                return QtCore.Qt.Unchecked
        return QtSql.QSqlQueryModel.data(self, index, role)


    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if index.column() not in (12):
            return False

        primaryKeyIndex = self.index(index.row(), 0)
        id = self.data(primaryKeyIndex)
        #self.clear()

        if index.column() == 12 and role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole:
            value2 = super(EditableShoSqlModel, self).data(index)
            if value2 != 0:
                ok = self.setAniStatus(id, value)
                return QtCore.Qt.Unchecked
            else:
                ok = self.setAniStatus(id, value)
                return QtCore.Qt.Checked
            return True
        self.refresh()
        return ok

    def refresh(self):
        MainWindow.AllShotsFromProject ()

    def setAniStatus(self, id, Number):
        mon = Number
        if mon != False:
           mon = 1
        else:
           mon = 0
        print "ANIS"            
        query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        sql = "UPDATE Shot SET Ani= '{0}' WHERE idShot = {1}".format(int(mon), id.toString())
        query.prepare(sql)
        print 'lastQuery:', query.lastQuery()
        return query.exec_()
```

Comment: `QTableView` can display checkboxes without a delegate. Look for the [`CheckStateRole`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum). If you use the proper `data`, `setData` and `flags` methods for your model, you should be fine without any delegate. Is there any specific reason you want a delegate?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have a table where several of the columns are editable mostly text, but some checkboxes and eventually some buttons. when trying the method of the checkstaterole all of my columns become checkbox. How do I tell it to leave the other columns as they are?

Comment: For `CheckStateRole`, if you return `None` you won't get any checkboxes. If you return a check box state, you'll see checkboxes. So check the column and return `None` or the state.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to isolate the checkbox to a determined column. The only problem I have now, is that when I click on the chekbo they disapear. They are doing the right thing underneath (writing 0 or 1 to a database). Any idea why it would be disapearing?

Comment: Hi Avaris, I posted the new code and an image explaining the problem. The problem of the checkbox disappearing is fixed, I had a self.clear() somewhere in the code... But I still can check the cehckboxes ;(

Comment: There are a couple problems with your model. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`if index.column() not in (12):` will not work. `(12)` is same as `12` and you can't do `foo in 12`. That's a `TypeError`. You *can* do `foo in (12,)` but there is no need. That's simple `foo == 12`.

`setData` should return `True` or `False` that indicates `success`, but you are returning `QtCore.Qt.Unchecked` and `QtCore.Qt.Checked`. That won't fit well.

If you don't want to show `0/1`, you should do that in `data` by simply returning `None` for `DisplayRole`.

This should do what you want:

```py
class EditableShoSqlModel(QtSql.QSqlQueryModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(EditableShoSqlModel, self).__init__(parent)


    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super(EditableShoSqlModel, self).flags(index)
        if index.column() == 12:
            flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        return flags


    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.column() == 12:
            value = super(EditableShoSqlModel, self).data(index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole:
                if value != 0:
                    return QtCore.Qt.Checked
                else:
                    return QtCore.Qt.Unchecked
            else:
                return None

        return super(EditableShoSqlModel, self).data(index, role)


    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if index.column() == 12 and role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole:
            # `id` is a built-in function
            id_ = self.data(self.index(index.row(), 0)).toString()
            state, ok = value.toInt()
            if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                value = 1
            else:
                value = 0
            result = self.setAniStatus(id_, value)
            if result:
                # we modified the db, we need to query again
                self.refresh()
            return result

        # I don't know what `refresh` does. But normally you don't need that
        return False


    def refresh(self):
        # something that re-queries the model.
        #self.setQuery('SELECT * FROM Shot')


    def setAniStatus(self, id_, value):          
        query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        sql = "UPDATE Shot SET Ani= {0} WHERE idShot = {1}".format(value, id_)
        query.prepare(sql)
        print 'lastQuery:', query.lastQuery()
        return query.exec_()
```

Comment: Hi Avaris, thanks so much for this sample code. I think I am finally getting there. The only thing I dont quite understand is at what point in the class does the table "refresh" to show the new checkbox values? The check box values are passing to the database but are not showing in my tableview immediately.Only when I reload  the table I can see them..

Comment: @user1028826: Yes, sorry my bad. `QSqlQueryModel` is a one way (read-only) model, so it doesn't know that you changed the value in the database. You need to re-query the model after you made a change. I guess that's what your `refresh` method was doing?

Comment: @user1028826: I've edited my answer (and corrected a couple of mistakes too).

Comment: Yes! my refresh was querying the table again.. Thanks SO much Avaris, it's all working now.. I wish I could buy you a beer!!!